# What is the first mention of the modelling cycle in OR?

Tags: reference-request

The first reference to the modelling cycle (reality, model, solution, implementation) for operations research I found, is the paper "Operations research from the viewpoint of general systems theory" by Sagasti and Mitroff from 1973. However, they don't cite anyone else for it, but they also act as if it is common knowledge. Is there some source the modelling cycle is usually attributed to?

Comment: Similar approaches are known and used since decades or even centuries outside Operations Research, in Science in general. This explains why Sagasti and Mitroff considered the approach as common knowledge. What is interesting in the recent decades is that the implementation phase has considerably evolved, thanks to the rise of computers.

Comment: Yeah, I often see something similar under the name "design thinking" propagated as a new revolutionary idea in other fields....

Comment: You're right, most of the idea is infinitely rebranded ;-) But this is very good in fact because a way to spread them, especially along the time.